# python selenium - Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to populate form fields via selenium in python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Firefox()        
driver.get("http://www.miralinks.ru/")
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
login = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[placeholder="Логин"]')
hov = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(login)
hov.perform()
login.clear()
login.send_keys("login")
pwd = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[placeholder="Пароль"]')
pwd.clear()
pwd.send_keys("pass")
```

but this fails with exception:

> Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated

Why this happens and gow to fix this?

webdriver `__version__ = '2.45.0'`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are u moving to that element?

Comment: I thought it was some sort of trap on site.. move to enable element

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that there are two other `input` elements with `placeholder="Логин"` and `placeholder="Пароль"` which are invisible. Make your *CSS selectors specific to the login form*:

```
login = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('form#loginForm input[placeholder="Логин"]')
pwd = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('form#loginForm input[placeholder="Пароль"')
```

Comment: thank you, this works, but i don't understand why? both selectors points to same element..

Comment: Your answer helped me figure out a very similar problem I was having (presence of 'password' field in both sign up form and login header).
That being said, I resolved it by using xpath like so:
`//form[@name="signup.form"]//input[@name = "password"]`

Answer (score 2):

Use a wait function before the element that gave the error.

The webdriver is trying to interact with an element not completely loaded.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was because another element was overlaying the input box. In my case, there was a fancy label in place of a placeholder that animates upwards on click.

The trick was to click on the label first to trigger the animation and then fill in the input field

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well, but in my case the cause was slightly different.  I needed to specify the size of the window before navigating to the page:

```
driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(width, height);
```

This is because the default window size was rendering the page at a width where a media query had hidden the element, which caused the *"Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated"* error.

Answer (score 0):

Here xpath selectors working.

```
login = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id=\'loginForm\']/div/div[1]/input')
pwd = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id=\'loginForm\']/div/div[2]/input')
```

or same but css selector

```
login = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('form#loginForm [name="data[User][login]"]')
pwd = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('form#loginForm [name="data[User][password]"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it takes time to load the page. You can add wait statement.
Try using "Thread.sleep(3000)"