# Selenium and PhantomJS - can not sendKeys()

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, screenshotexception

When I try to send keys than I get an error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: {"errorMessage":"Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated"...
    at main.Main_1.main(Main_1.java:39)

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ScreenshotException: Screen shot has been taken...

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: {"errorMessage":"Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated"...
```

a code:

```
driver.get("site url");
wait.until( ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("query")) );
System.out.println(driver.getTitle()); //this line works
driver.findElement(By.name("query")).sendKeys("test"); //error here (Main_1.java:39)
```

What is the reason?

Comment: Are you sure that the element is in the viewport? Have you tried to increase the viewport (window size)?

Comment: @ArtjomB. It's phantomjs... but I know that the element is in the viewport. Why then the second line of the code works?

Comment: Have a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29346595/python-selenium-element-is-not-currently-interactable-and-may-not-be-manipulat

Comment: @Grasshopper that helped me

Answer (score 0):

First click that element:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("query")).click();
```

then pass data by using `sendKeys`:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("query")).sendKeys("test");
```