# How to login into Openload.co using python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to login into openload.co using python Selenium Chrome Driver but I am getting the following error:

> Message: element not interactable

I am using the following code and the error occurs in the last line of the code where I am not able to send the keys to the input tag.

```
from selenium import webdriver
path="path_to_chrome_driver"  #add chromedriver path
driver=webdriver.Chrome(path)
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver.get('https://openload.co/login')
email = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginform-email"]')
email.send_keys("example@xyz.com")
```

I searched for the problem on stackoverflow and landed on the following link [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29346595/python-selenium-element-is-not-currently-interactable-and-may-not-be-manipulat) which says that probably it is not pointing to correct xpath or css_selector. But I can't seem to find it.
What wrong am I doing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because there's a modal in the HTML made visible when you click the top right "Sign in" button. There's a duplication of ids. Could you try passing the password and username like this *http://username:password@openload.co/* ?

@john try this, works for me:

```
driver.get('https://openload.co/login')
emails = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginform-email"]')
emails[1].send_keys("example@xyz.com")
```

Comment: So, basically I am using https://openload.co/login which does not have a model loading problem. But I gave a try with https://username:password@openload.co//? and it didn't work.

Comment: Open the developer console and refresh the page. [this is the problem](https://i.imgur.com/lNByano.png)

Comment: The problem is the model, It's badly designed and stays hidden unless we click on the "sign in" button.

Answer (score 1):

Try to click on the element before sending keys.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginform-email"]').click()
```

Because of this the cursor will be active on the email textbox field so the element should interactivable.

Comment: Hi, I have already written this piece of line in my 2nd last line of the code. See above

Comment: Sorry, I missed the click()method from the end of the line. Try copypaste this one.

Comment: need to add this line `sigin=driver.find_element_by_class_name("sign-in-button").click()` and now it's working. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two forms on page: first one for SignIn, second for LogIn. Both have input fields with the same `@id` values. You need to select form for LogIn:

```
email = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h1[.="Login"]/following::*[@id="loginform-email"]')
email.send_keys("example@xyz.com")
```

Comment: Great! This works as well, Can you tell me how did you get this xpath for the login form?

Comment: @johnmich , I don't use tools for XPath generation - just created by myself. There are many tutorials for learning XPath (like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) or [this](https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html))